# How to merge sObject's data to String

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need help to write a method which will do some kind of string merge. I have an object having some data. It may be any object.Like this:

```
Account oAccount = [select id,Name from Account limit 1];
```

And I have a certain string like this:

```
String sTemp = "Name belongs to {oAccount.Name}";
```

I need to call a method. Suppose the method name is `mergeString`.

```
mergeString(oAccount, sTemp);
```

The method should be able to return merged strings like :

> "Name belongs to Kumar" {If Account name is Kumar}

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the merging field at the end of the string, wouldn't be easier to append it rather than replace it? You can create a method that will append strings:

```
public String mergeString(sObject recordObject, String eixstingString)
{
    // Some sObjects like Contact and Lead have FirstName and others have Name field
    return eixstingString + (recordObject.get('Name') == null ? (String)recordObject.get('FirstName') : (String)recordObject.get('Name'));
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
String sTemp = 'Name belongs to ';
Account oAccount = [select Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
String mergedString = mergeString(oAccount, sTemp);
```

If you had the placeholder in the middle of the string:

```
String sTemp = 'Name belongs to {recordName} and there is more static text here';
```

Then you could use the replace method:

```
public String mergeString(sObject recordObject, String eixstingString)
{
    // Some sObjects like Contact and Lead have FirstName and others have Name field
    return eixstingString.replace('{recordName}', (recordObject.get('Name') == null ? (String)recordObject.get('FirstName') : (String)recordObject.get('Name')));
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on your comments below it looks like you're trying to dynamically replace a placeholder with the field specified there. I think this final method should get you going:

```
public String mergeString(sObject recordObject, String eixstingString)
{
    String templateString = eixstingString.substring(eixstingString.indexOf('{'), eixstingString.indexOf('}') + 1); // results in {Account.AccountNumber}
    String fieldName = eixstingString.substring(eixstingString.indexOf('.') + 1, eixstingString.indexOf('}')); // results in "AccountNumber"
    return eixstingString.replace(templateString, (String)recordObject.get(fieldName));
}
```

**Keep in mind that this will not work if you have multiple `.`, `{` or `}` characters in your template. Also you must query the field that is specified in the template.**

Comment: Thanks for help but  i want to pass a string which i got from sObject's field after soql Account = [select Name, accountnumber, billingcity, billingstate, billingcountry, billingpostalcode, phone,Fax,Rating,CreatedBy.companyname from Account where Id =: oId LIMIT 1] ;
    if(Account != null){
      for(Document tempDoc : lstSelectedDoc){
        sTemp = tempDoc.Template_Info__c;
        oppText.value +=  sTemp ;
        oppText.value += '</tBody></table>';   
        
      }
    } Note: Template_Info__c value is like  {Name is '+Account.accountnumber+'}

Comment: `mergeString(oAccount, oAccount.Template_Info__c);` - Just pass the string that you want to use as a base as a second parameter

Comment: I have tried this but actually i return whole string as it is its not renders object's value to string

Comment: Make sure your template placeholder matches the first parameter in the replace method. E.g. `Template = 'Name is {account.Name}'`, your method should be `return existingString.replace('{account.Name}', (String)recordObject.get('Name'));`

Comment: Thanks for your support but I cant use '{account.Name}' for replace actually this will be unknown, means there can be any value from object ,so i can't hard coded replace param.It should be dynamically means any value from object

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I think this logic gonna work. I really appreciate your valuable time for me. Thanks a lot ... Keep going brother ....

Comment: No worries. Don't hesitate to use the upvote button for other answers. It really helps the community when everyone votes. Not always the best answer is the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple piece of code

```
public string mergeString(oAccount, sTemp) {
  string str = 'Name belongs to '+oAccount; //or str = sTemp+' '+oAccount;
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but string should not be inside of method we have just pass string to method . One thing more i want to pass a string which i got from sObject's field after soql

Comment: update my answer see the comment part. You can pass as many argument as you want and then add them.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code in the merge string method

```
String mergedString = sTemp + oAccount.Name;
Return mergedString;
```